# Problema ao visualizar dados de uma grid dentro do code behind

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Em uma GridView estou tentado pegar os dados referentes a uma linha onde o `checkbox == true`.

Consigo pegar o valor do checkbox, porém não consigo pegar os outros valores referentes a linha.

```
while (i < gvwNot.Rows.Count)
{
    GridViewRow row = gvwNot.Rows[i];
    CheckBox isChecked = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");
    //TextBox id = (TextBox)row.FindControl("ID");
    //TextBox nome = (TextBox)row.FindControl("NOME");

    if (isChecked.Checked == true)
    {
        string id = gvwNot.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
        string nome = gvwNot.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text;

        qry = sb.ToString();
        qtd = qtd + 1;
    }

    i++;
}



<asp:GridView ID="gvwNot" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="Id"
    AllowPaging="True"
    AllowSorting="true"
    PageSize="10"
    CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" >

    <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <input id="chkAll" onclick="javascript: SelecionaTodosChecks(this);" runat="server" type="checkbox"  />
            </HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>


        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
            <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("ID") %>    </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Protocolo">
            <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("NOME") %>    </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
    <PagerSettings Mode="NextPrevious" NextPageText="Próximo" PreviousPageText="Anterior" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Você fala o ID e o nome?

Comment: @Marconi Sim, no code behide, ele aparece vazio.

Comment: É chamado algum evento de algum botão pra rodar esse código?

Comment: sim, isso é dentro do Onclick do botão, onde tb tenho um OnClientClick com uma validação Javascript onde verifica se o campo foi digitado.

Comment: Entendi, seu botão está dentro da Grid ou fora?

Comment: Fora da gridview.

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui. Tem até um demo. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/GridView-with-CheckBox-Get-Selected-Rows-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25797/discussion-between-germano-sampaio-and-marconi).

Answer (score 0):

Pelo o que eu entendi você precisa apenas mostrar o ID e o Nome no seu gridview.
Você pode alterar para BoundField, que irá te mostrar o texto e quando você tentar acessar no code behind irá funcionar normalmente. Altere seu trecho de código do Id e Nome para o trecho abaixo:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />

<asp:BoundField DataField="NOME" HeaderText="Protocolo" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
```